# Quick Search Form Not Submitting MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, search, submit

I currently have a partial view that renders at the top of every page on the site. The point of this partial view is to provide a form that lets the user do a quick search. I have set the partial view form up as follows:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <div class="col-md-7" style="text-align: right">                          
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm col-sm-6 pull-right">
                        @Html.TextBox("caseReference")
                        <button type="submit">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>   
            }
            @Html.Partial("_MainNavigation")
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("form").on("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var request = { caseReference: $('#caseReference').val() };
            submitForm(request, '@Url.Action("CaseSearch", "QuickSearch", new { area = "Search" })');
        });
    });

</script>
```

However under the page source the form action renders as a request to the home page with a post action. I have read numerous examples and this task seems very straight forward. Would it be a better idea to use the parameters on the @html.BeginForm() method?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this other than just by saying "yes" ... it would give an identical result but with fewer things that could go wrong.

Comment: Yes use the parameters on the @html.BeginForm() method. And make sure you don't have a form within another form.

Comment: So after debugging in developer tools, it is making a post request to 'Search/QuickSearch/CaseSearch' which seems to be correct and the request body contains the caseReference. However I am getting a 404 error 'HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.'

Comment: Just to be clear the 404 error is in regards tot he 'Search/QuickSearch/CaseSearch' URL

Answer (score 0):

So after spending a few hours researching, I have finally got the quick search functionality to work on the home page of my site. In the razorview I have the following code:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm col-sm-6 pull-right">
                @Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox().Name("name").Mask("000000/0000").Deferred()
                <button id="search" type="submit">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#search").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var value = $('#name').val();
        value = value.replace(/[/]/g, "_");
        var refVal = value;
        var url = '@Url.Action("Action", "Contoller", new { area = "Area" })' + '//' + refVal;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json;",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    window.location.href = result.url;
                }
                else {
                    bootbox.alert(result.message);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

However in regards to the following line:

```
        var url = '@Url.Action("Action", "Contoller", new { area = "Area" })' + '//' + refVal;
```

If I hard code the url and append the search term it works on the Home page because we are at the root directory but from other pages it fails, To get around this I tried to use @Url.Action. However this is producing the following result in the html soure code:

```
        var url = '' + '//' + refVal;
```

Is there a certain way to use the URL.Action method from withing JS?